# IntelliJ: Additional indent in function arguments

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When I use Reformat File in IntelliJ Idea, IDE adds additional space in function argument to align it in one line with function.

I can't find option in Code Style to disable in on change configuration.

Code:

```js
export const getApplicationFormInstance = ({
                                             consents,
                                             dealer_code,
                                             source,
                                             rent_subscription,
                                             comment = null,
                                             ...baseOptions
                                           }: IApplicationFormOptions): FormInstanceType<IApplicationModel> => {
  return false;
}
```

Screenshot of Error from ESLint:

[image: Screenshot of Error]

I try to find way to fix it in IDE, not in ESLint like:
`"@typescript-eslint/indent": "off"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the code you want to format differently.
2. Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and invoke `Adjust code style settings`
3. Under the `Wrapping and Braces` tab uncheck the `Align when multiline` checkbox

That should get you the formatter behaviour you want.

Comment: Thanks!
Never know about these feature.

Comment: It is not well known, but very useful in cases like this.